# Antd Select - how to reset the position of the dropdown when re-opening the select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

**Step to reproduce**
1.Click and Open the Select
[image]
2.Scroll to the bottom
[image]
3.Close the Select by clicking outside
4.Reopen the Select
5.The Select is still on the position as Step 2

**Expected Behaviour**
5.The Select should be the same as the one in Step 1

Is it possible to do it?

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
    import './index.css';
    import { Select } from 'antd';
import type { SelectProps } from 'antd';

const options: SelectProps['options'] = [];

for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  options.push({
    value: i.toString(36) + i,
    label: i.toString(36) + i,
  });
}

const handleChange = (value: string) => {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
};

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Select
    mode="tags"
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    onChange={handleChange}
    tokenSeparators={[',']}
    options={options}
  />
);

export default App;
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/15lgd3?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the scroll the position by passing a ref to Select Component & listen for dropdown visible change using `onDropdownVisibleChange` prop. When it's visible, you can move the scroll position to first element by passing `index: 0` in `scrollTo` method.

```
import { MutableRefObject, useRef } from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';
import type { SelectProps } from 'antd';
import type { BaseSelectRef } from 'rc-select';

const options: SelectProps['options'] = [];

for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
    options.push({
        value: i.toString(36) + i,
        label: i.toString(36) + i
    });
}

const handleChange = (value: string) => {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const ref = useRef() as MutableRefObject<BaseSelectRef>;

    const onDropdownVisibleChange = (open: boolean) => {
        if (open && ref.current) {
            ref.current.scrollTo({ index: 0 });
        }
    };

    return (
        <Select
            mode='tags'
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            onChange={handleChange}
            tokenSeparators={[',']}
            options={options}
            ref={ref}
            onDropdownVisibleChange={onDropdownVisibleChange}
        />
    );
};

export default App;
```